# Delete trigger is not working when fire from c# but working in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

i made a after delete trigger on a table1 and in this trigger i insert the deleted data in another table name tab2.
when i execute the delete stored procedure of table1 from sql server 2005 then trigger working fine but when i execute delete stored procedure of table1 from c# then it is not working properly.
Help me

Comment: Explain "not working properly" - does the trigger fire or not? Is data not running? Please post your C# code you are using to call the stored procedure, so one can see if there is anything fishy there.

Comment: No way! You must be doing something wrong. I call shenanigans. Even toy databases like SQLServer wouldn't be _that_ brain-dead :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Check the login in your connection string. Are those the same credentials you used to sign in to Management Studio? If not, verify that the user has permission to access the trigger, as well as permission to do whatever the trigger does.